# not able to find the element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

Hi I would like to find an element on a web page and further provide the string in to the text box. The inspected web page looks like below.

```
<div>
    <label class="inforScreenReaderText" for="login">User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="inforTextbox" placeholder="User ID">
</div>
```

I have tried all the options below but nothing worked. It would be really great if you could provide the solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='login']") 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='login']") 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='inforTextbox']") 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='login']") 
driver.find_element(By.ID, "login")
```

and getting one of the errors below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='login']"}
```

Comment: check for `iframes` and check add `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` - this will let the page load before throwing nosuchelement

Comment: Try to apply [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

Comment: I tried driver.implicitly_wait(10) but no luck

Comment: Have you tried ".//input[@id='login']" instead of "//input[@id='login']" ?

Comment: Tried just now but didn`t work. Now I am looking if java script is enabled or not for the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below xpath

```
//input[@placeholder = 'User ID']
```

Answer (score 0):

The web page has the frames so earlier it was not accessing the elements.
I selected first frame like below. Then able to select the further elements.
Thank you all

```
driver.switch_to_frame('topframe')
```